# Geração de Excel em asp classico gerando planilha em branco

Tags: microsoft-excel, asp, iis

Possuo um arquivo testeexcel.asp que para geração de excel:

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<% 
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=excelTest.xls"
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
%>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

só que ao abrir no excel o arquivo fica em branco. Se eu abrí-lo no notepad++ salvar sem alterar nada e tentar abrir no excel novamente ele abre normalmente.
Segue o link para teste [104.41.63.35/testeexcel.asp](http://104.41.63.35/testeexcel.asp)

Tentei configurar encoding do arquivo mas não funcionou de jeito algum. Alguma dica?

Ambiente: Windows server 2012 com IIS 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri a causa do problema e a solução.
Recentemente foi instalado algumas atualizações de segurança que bloqueiam a exibição de planilhas excel geradas enviadas pela internet.

- Windows Update KB3115262 (Excel 2013)
- Windows Update KB3115130 (Excel 2010)

**Para poder visualizar planilhas geradas existem três opções:**

1. Desinstalar as atualizações (não recomendado)
2. Configurar o Excel para abrir arquivos da internet (recomendado)

   - Abrir o Excel
   - No menu Arquivo, selecione opções
   - Clique em Central de confiabilidade... na aba esquerda
   - Clique no botão Configurações da Central de Confiabilidade na aba direita
   - Clique em Modo de Exibição Protegido
   - Desmarque a caixa Habilitar Modo de Exibição Protegido para arquivos originados da Internet
3. Desbloquear o arquivo

   - Faça download do arquivo
   - Em vez de abrir diretamente, visualize o arquivo na pasta
   - Clique com o botão direito do mouse em cima do arquivo
   - Selecione Propriedades
   - Selecione a caixa Desbloquear (Unblock)
   - Clique em OK ou Apply